I can't add buttons with filling from JSON file
I have an html project to which I need to add 4 buttons filled from a JSON file using an array.
The parameters are taken depending on the link id.
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mt-4">
        <a href="#" id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">
            <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-1"> Button 1
        </a>
        <a href="#" id="button-2" class="btn btn-primary">
            <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-2"> Button 2
        </a>
        <a href="#" id="button-3" class="btn btn-primary">
            <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-3"> Button 3
        </a>
        <a href="#" id="button-4" class="btn btn-primary">
            <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-4"> Button 4
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

        


$(document).ready(function () {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const repoId = urlParams.get('id');



    $.getJSON('repositories.json', function (data) {
        const repo = data.find(r => r.id === repoId);


    

        if (repo.buttons && Array.isArray(repo.buttons)) {
            repo.buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
                const btn = $(`#button-${index + 1}`);
                if (btn.length > 0) {
                    btn.attr('href', button.link || '#');
                    btn.find('img').attr('src', button.icon || 'default-icon.png');
                    btn.find('span').text(button.text || `Button ${index + 1}`);
                }
            });
        }
    });

        </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>

Code from JSON file:
[
    {
        "id": "repo1",

        "buttons": [
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl1"
            },
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl2"
            },
            {
                
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl3"
            },
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl4"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": "repo2",

        "buttons": [
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl1"
            },
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl2"
            },
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl3"
            },
            {
                "link": "exmpl.html",
                "icon": "exmpl.png",
                "text": "btn exmpl4"
            }
        ]

    }
]


I tried renaming repo.buttons to repoId.buttons, but it didn't help (fixed the error in the console, but the problem remained)
Console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: repo is not defined

"Uncaught ReferenceError: repo is not defined" - Which line of the code shown is producing this error?  Can you provide a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet (hard-coding known input data as needed) which demonstrates the problem?  What debugging have you done with your browser's development tools?

repo depends on finding repoId in the data, and repoId is from the search params; what are the url search params?

@mykaf url search params are id
exmaple:
link id is repo1

I can only get that error with this code if the search param id doesn't match one in the data.

@mykaf It matches because there is no error that the id was not found and the rest of the information is loaded

Where are you expecting to find an  error that the repoId was not found? What do you mean "the rest of the information is loaded"? Loaded where?

For data.find(...), "if no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned" (per MDN). It won't throw an error.

@mykaf I can't send a full json file, but it contains information about the text that should be displayed on the page. Page has alert:    'if (!repoId) {
alert('RepoId is not found');
return;
}' that checks repoid

Then, again, you need to indicate which line is throwing the error, and perhaps include that alert (and relevant code) in the code here. Because this code can find the repoid. Perhaps there is another instance where it's not being found.

Consider the following: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vax2e167/
HTML
<div>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around mt-4">
    <a href="#" id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">
      <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-1" /> <span>Button 1</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="button-2" class="btn btn-primary">
      <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-2" /> <span>Button 2</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="button-3" class="btn btn-primary">
      <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-3" /> <span>Button 3</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="button-4" class="btn btn-primary">
      <img src="" alt="Icon" id="icon-button-4" /> <span>Button 4</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

JavaScript
var myData =
  '[{"id":"repo1","buttons":[{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl1"},{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl2"},{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl3"},{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl4"}]},{"id":"repo2","buttons":[{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl1"},{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl2"},{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl3"},{"link":"exmpl.html","icon":"exmpl.png","text":"btn exmpl4"}]}]'

$(function () {
  //var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  //var repoId = urlParams.get("id")
  var repoId = "repo2"
  $.post("/echo/json/", { json: myData }, function (data) {
    var repo = data.find((r) => r.id === repoId)
    if (repo.buttons && Array.isArray(repo.buttons)) {
      repo.buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
        var btn = $("#button-" + (index + 1))
        if (btn.length > 0) {
          btn.attr("href", button.link || "#")
          btn.find("img").attr("src", button.icon || "default-icon.png")
          btn.find("span").text(button.text || `Button ${index + 1}`)
        }
      })
    }
  })
})

In this example, <span> tags had to be added to the HTML to make your Script work properly. JSFiddle is a good way to test mock JSON as it has an Echo feature.

Please use a Stack Snippet instead of a remote jsfiddle.

@Barmar do they also have an echo feature?

No, but you don't need that to answer the question. Just hard-code the value of data.
